# I can't connect Mariadb remotely in Oracle Cloud

Tags: virtual-machine, firewall, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I allowed all access for oracle cloud.

inside firewall.

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
```

outside firewall
[image]

But i still can't access vm remotely.
What I'm missing?